# Can I keep files' revision history?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I am looking to purchase additional storage.  However what is important to me is that once I have synced data to the cloud, that if I delete the file locally, it DOES NOT get deleted in the cloud.  Is this possible with UbuntuOne?

Additonally I note that I can only sync data from C:/user/nick/documents etc.  I need to be able to sync data from drives other than C: in Windows.  Using Ubuntu I can select what every directories I want.

On my Windows machine Drive c: is an SSD drive and therefor I do not keep data on there.  Please can you give me some indication when this restriction on Windows will be lifted.

I have multiple Machines 2 x Ubuntu 10.10, 2 x Windows 7 Ultimate a Samsung Tablet and an HTC Android Phone. All deveices need to be able to send and receive data to the cloud storage.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu One is not a backup solution, but a file syncing software. Therefore, if you delete a file from your local device, it will delete it from the servers too.

Aditionally, there is no support for syncing folders outside of your profile on windows.

So, Ubuntu One doesn't seem to be the right tool for your situation.

There are, however, workarounds for both problems: you may sync a backup of your data. backup to a folder, then sync that one.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One doesn't allow you to restore a previous version of a file, but Déjà Dup (called "Backup" in Ubuntu) does. And Déjà Dup can backup to Ubuntu One. So yes, you can. Better than dropbox actually.

Open the "backup" app. Tell it which folder your want it to take care of. Tell it to backup every X and to keep older backup for Y time. Then tell it to backup to Ubuntu One. Setting it up is confusingly easy and not backing up, if only locally, should be a capital offence.

**For example**, I might set it to backup every day and keep the backups for 6 month. If I delete a file accidentally, and I'm online, it will get deleted on my Ubuntu One sync. However, I can just navigate up to the folder containing it, right click it and one of the options available will be "revert to a previous version". Could be yesterday, or 3 month ago... Sometimes it takes time to notice a file is missing.

Goes without saying, it eats up quite some space. It says that it will flush old backups when space starts running out. Haven't tested that.

Comment: Was about to post this, I've used Déjà Dup for quite a while with UbuntuOne and never had any problems, highly recommended, though I would chec the cross-OS compatibility for Déjà Dup, might not be able to do this across windows machines/non-Ubuntu OS smartphones/tablets.